# Свойство AutoSizeMode для TabControl

Tags: c#, winforms

В ячейке `TableLayoutControl` содержится `TabControl`. В `TabControl` содержатся страницы со следующими свойствами:

```
this.AutoSize = true;
this.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
```

В странице присутствует один корневой экземпляр `TableLayoutPanel`. Который содержит другие компоненты и обладает свойствами:

```
this.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; 
this.AutoSize = true;
this.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
```

Алгоритм масштабирования строк `TableLayoutPanel`:

```
this.RowStyles.Clear();
for (int i = 0; i < this.RowCount - 1; i++)
{
    RowStyle rs = new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize);
    this.RowStyles.Add(rs);
}
this.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100));
```

Свойства компонента содержащемся в строке таблицы:

```
this.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

**Вопрос:** После добавления страниц `TabPage` в `TabControl`, хочу уменьшить высоту `TabControl` до максимальной по высоте страницы содержащейся в нем, а ширину растянуть до максимальной возможной ширины родительского компонента.
Как я могу это сделать? Свойство AutoSizeMode отсутствует для компонента `TabControl` и он не уменьшается автоматически в зависимости от его содержимого.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В документации ясно написано что свойства `AutoSize` и `AutoSizeMode` бессмысленны для компонентов `TabControl` и `TabPage`. Исходя из этого добиться авторегулирования высоты пользуясь только компонентами `TabControl` и `TabPage` нельзя.

Однако есть способ добиться этого авторегулирования вручную следующим способом:

1) Положить во все `TabPage` компонент `Panel` который будет новым контейнером компонентов страницы у которого выставить свойство `Autosize = true;`.

2) Затем в конце формирования компонента `TabControl` пробежать по всем страницам и получить размер каждого компонента `Panel`.

3) Применить максимальный размер найденный с помощью пробега на предыдущем шаге.